# Does strong convergence in $L^2$ implies any trace convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have strong convergence in $L^2$: $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Now additionally if we assume $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, and $u_n$ are some special $L^2$ functions which have trace defined, i.e. piecewise polynomials.

Is it always true that
$u_n|_{\partial \Omega}$
converges weakly/strongly to
$u|_{\partial \Omega}$
in
$L^2(\partial \Omega)$?
As pointed out in the comment, this is not true.

Comment: Try $u_n = x^n$ on $\Omega = [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So does there exist a characterization of trace convergence that is not as strong as H^1 convergence?

Comment: there are trace theorems for fractional Sobolev spaces, so you can google those. For example, under suitable asssumptions on boundary smoothness, we have a continuous trace operator $H^{s}(\Omega)\to H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$ when $s>\frac{1}{2}$ (and hence trivially $H^s\to L^2$).